# Как сделать сервер Apache доступным в интернете?

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, сервер

Привет! Я установил Apache 2 и PHP 5 по [этой](http://php.su/prepare/?apache2_php5_win) инструкции. http://localhost/ открывается идеально, но как сделать так, чтобы то, что открывается по localhost открывалось по моему IP с любого компьютера, а не только с моего?

Answer (score 1):

Привет!
В файле host - прописать ваш IP, открыть 80 порт (файервол чтоб не блокировал), настроить файл конфига apache

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы к вашему сайту(Который находится у Вас на Вашем компьютеры) был доступ из интернета нужно сделать проброс портов. Если конечно есть такая возможность.